# how to send fcm notification to multiple device in single fcm reqest

Tags: android, notifications

i want to send notification to multiple device in single fcm request.
my notification text is same for all devices.i have to send more then 10000 notification at same time to all user and text is same so i want to send all notification in minimum fcm request. 
I am using c# asmx service.
hear is my code.

string regid="fcm_reg_id1,fcm_reg_id2" like this.

string applicationID = "abcd";

string SENDER_ID = "123456";

```
            string regid="c_Z5yRoj4TY:APA91bGry2g_CIA1xaRy_LscxOvFX6YHqasKA96TjpG6yi1yytNyM5rtGL6DgxjGMSE5c74d7VdSL6W8zxO1ixVMlpVMwdgcrsGUWV0VfdbddC2XD","c_Z5yRoj4TY:APA91bGry2g_CIA1xaRy_LscxOvFX6YHqasKA96TjpG6yi1yytNyM5rtGL6DgxjGMSE5c74d7";

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            String collaps_key = "Score_update";

            string json = "collapse_key=abcd" + "&data.header=cricket&registration_id=" + regId + "&data.notificationId=" + notificationId + "&data.message=" + msg;

            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: key={0}", SENDER_ID));

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(json);
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
                using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                        retmsgid = result.ToString();
                        if (retmsgid.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            ResponceString = result.ToString();
                            string[] msgsplits = retmsgid.Split(',');
                            string[] msg1 = msgsplits[0].ToString().Split(':');
                            ReturnMessageId = msg1[1].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ReturnMessageId = "0";
                        }
                    }
                    httpResponse.Close();
                    httpResponse.Dispose();
                    httpWebRequest = null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can perform this from web using IMEI numbers(Need to Register IMEI Numbers in your backend). So, you need to post your message using webservices from your mobile device. Now you can broadcast your messages from web using IMEI number registered devices.

Comment: i want to send multiple notification in single request in above code i want to add multiple registration id and send it.

Answer (score 7):

Since [FCM does not allow](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream) specifying more than 1000 registration IDs when sending a message:

> This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or
>   IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at
>   most 1000 registration tokens.

You only option is sending a message to a [topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple#about_topic_messaging)

Comment: I want to send around message to around 100 registration Ids (Only Mobile devices) at one time. How do I Compose the request?

Comment: Actually my question was that only. May be I was not able to frame it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is possible solution for all looking for an approach to send notification to limited registered devices . (Less than 1000 devices) .
Considering the input for device ids as an string :

```
device_ids_input="code1,code2,code3,..";
```

Use this code snippets to execute command for sending notification.

```
string[] deviceIds = device_ids_input.Split(',');
    string hasSound = "1";
    string applicationID = "AIz------------------";
    string senderId = "73-------";


    WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    tRequest.Method = "post";
    tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    var data = new
    {
        registration_ids = deviceIds,
        data = new
        {
            title = messageTitle,
            full_text = messageBody,
            Sound = hasSound

        }
    };
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                {
                    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();


                }
            }
        }
    }
```